# Manifold that's not $\aleph_1$-separable

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, cardinals

I know that there are manifolds that are not separable, such as the long line $\omega_1 \times [0, 1) \setminus \{(0, 0)\}$. Is there any manifold with no uncountable dense set of cardinality $\aleph_1$?

A line $\omega_2 \times [0, 1) \setminus \{(0, 0)\}$ wouldn't work since no neighborhoods of $(\omega_1, 0)$ are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. Would something else work?

Comment: Actually, separability is (usually? often?) part of the definition of manifold. I.e., the long line is *not* a manifold. Then again, you can simply take a large enough set with discrete topology (you never demanded connectedness)

Comment: @Hagen: Usually, but not always; there is a fairly extensive literature on non-metrizable manifolds, for instance, and the long line is definitely one of them. Connectedness **is** part of the definition, however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is at least consistent that every manifold have a dense subset of cardinality $\omega_1$: every manifold has cardinality $2^\omega=\mathfrak{c}$, so under $\text{CH}$ every manifold has cardinality $\omega_1$. (This is **Theorem 2.9** in Peter Nyikos, *The Theory of Nonmetrizable Manifolds*, in *Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology*, K. Kunen & J.E. Vaughan, eds., North Holland, 1984.) However, in section **3.7** he constructs a manifold of cellularity (and therefore density) $\mathfrak{c}$; under $\neg\text{CH}$ it has no dense subset of cardinality $\omega_1$.

Comment: Hm, where did my answer go wrong?

Comment: @Noah: The manifold that he constructs is ugly enough that I didn’t try to work through the details; he says that it’s the [Prüfer manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_manifold). It’s been decades since I last thought about any of this, but I suspect that you may need to have $\operatorname{cl}U_i\subseteq U_j$ for $i<j$ to ensure that the union is closed.

Comment: I'm confused--what definition of "manifold" are you using here?  I can't think of any natural definition that would allow the long line but not allow any manifolds of higher cardinality.  Maybe you are assuming the manifolds are connected?

Comment: @EricWofsey: Yes. Peter takes a manifold to be a connected space for which there is an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that each point has a nbhd homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$. (He does later look also at manifolds with boundary.)

Comment: I suppose they are also assumed to be Hausdorff?  Otherwise you can get arbitrarily large cardinality by "doubling" a point many times.

Comment: @EricWofsey: Yes; it’s fairly clear from context early on, though he doesn’t actually mention it until section **3.2** or so.

Answer (score 1):

For dimension $1$, I believe the answer is **no**.

Suppose $M$ is a connected Hausdorff space locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. Then we get a nondegenerate **betweenness** relation on $M$: $x$ is between $a$ and $b$ if every connected open set containing $a$ and $b$ also contains $x$. This in turn lets us define **intervals**: $[a,b]$ is the set of all $x$ which are between $a$ and $b$.

Now let $\langle x\rangle$ be the union of all intervals $[a,b]$ such that $x$ is between $a$ and $b$ and $[a,b]$ is homeomorphic to the usual unit interval. It's easy to check that $\langle x\rangle$ and $M\setminus\langle x\rangle$ are each open; since $M$ is connected this means $\langle x\rangle=M$.

But now consider a maximal sequence $\mathfrak{I}=(I_\eta)_{\eta<\alpha}$ of intervals containing $x$ such that for each $\eta_1<\eta_2<\alpha$ we have $I_{\eta_1}\subsetneq int(I_{\eta_2})$. Such a sequence can have length at most $\omega_1$ since otherwise we get an order-preserving injection of $\omega_1$ into the unit interval. And this gives us a dense subset of $\langle x\rangle=M$ of size $\le\omega_1$.